# How to line break after long word

Tags: php, html

Hey guys, I have a comments section and if a user writes something like blablablablablabla or something really long, the word doesn't break, but goes on straight, making the page look weird. How could I fix it and make it break the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be fixed with css

```
comment{
    word-wrap:break-word;    
}
```

Check it out here:

http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap/

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with CSS. Have a look at [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap):

```
.comment {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

will break overflowing words.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Note:**

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

not valid in W3C